# AEM- I"m trying creating page on AEM after going WKND Site > US > en,below interface is loading. what to do?

Tags: html, components, aem, aem-6, aem-project-archetype

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB1Tg.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJDSM.png)

AEM- I"m trying creating page on AEM after going WKND Site > US > en,below interface is loading. what to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your OTB clientlibs are not loading on your browser.

1. Are you running IE? If yes, switch to Chrome or Firefox. IE is dead.
2. Do you have your application installed or this is simply vanilla AEM instance? If this is vanilla AEM instance and NO custom application, its not worth to troubleshoot. Simply thrash the AEM server and recreate a new server. Meaning stop AEM instance, delete crx-quickstart folder and double click run the aem jar again.
3. Please add more context to your question. Add console errors you get and steps to replicate this issue. Also unusual server error log if any.